# How do I make sure my packages are up to date in 22.10, after the upgrade turned off most sources for apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 22.10

I accidentally upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 dev branch; it was less than 24 hours before the official release but I still have a lingering concern that some of my packages may not be the "correct" version for 22.10.

When I run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` it tells me that all packages are up to date; but when I look at the list of sources in [Software & Updates > Other Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGBtl.png), I can see that Kinetic Kudu turned off a lot of sources, and also that a lot of them still say "jammy". I am not very familiar with linux package managers, so I don't know if I should turn those back on or delete them, it is my understanding that when one of those sources is turned off apt can't check it for any updates so I worry there could be something that `apt update` isn't catching.

I apologize for this being a fairly open ended question, I'd greatly appreciate any advice or direction that could help me verify that my install of 22.10 doesn't have any out of date packages compared to the official release of Kinetic Kudu from October 20th 2022.

Comment: 3rd party repositories are *your* responsibility to manage. Being disabled happens in ANY release upgrade.

Comment: "*I am not very familiar with linux package managers*" suggests that you shouldn't be using so many PPAs. Maintaining those is your responsibility. A stock Ubuntu install uses no PPAs at all.

Comment: I found that screenshot confusing. You could start by looking at your sources in /etc/apt/sources.list and comparing what you see with what is in @user535733's answer. PPAs will have individual files in  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Ubuntu 22.10 system needs three Ubuntu repositories and pockets at a minimum:

```
kinetic main
kinetic-updates main
kinetic-security main
```

Everything after that is optional.

Different *pockets* are optional: universe, restricted, multiverse, backports

Different *non-Ubuntu sources* are optional: PPAs, third-party repositories.

Comment: So if these sources are listed uncommented in /etc/apt/sources.list, like this:  
    
`deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security main restricted`  
`deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted`  
  
that means I can be sure apt is checking those sources for updates? Even if they don't appear in the "Software & Updates" app?

Comment: To see if a source is actually being checked, read the output of `sudo apt update`. Never mix different releases (jammy vs. kinetic) -- that's the path to breaking your system.